# Camera Transition between 2 position / rotation, and follow a 3rd target

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, camera

I have setup a transition of camera between 2 transform, here the result in video:
https://youtu.be/rcwQ6KuEfMw

I have the information of the 2 transform:
- position (vector3)
- rotation (Quaternion)

And I do a Lerp, from Position1 to Position 2, and from Rotation1 to Rotation2:

```
Vector3 finalPosition = Vector3.Lerp(previousPosition, nextPosition, evaluateValueLerp);
Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(previousRotation, nextRotation, evaluateValueLerp);
```

Now the problem is, as you can see in the video: the player target (the car) is lost durring the transition, I would like to keep it always in the view.

How can I manage to do it ?

Thanks you !

Comment: you can add a new position between your position A and position B, first translate from A to a new position and from new position to position B. by that way you can easily solve the problem. I am assuming start position as position A and end position as position B.

Comment: Add a new position, or a new Transform ? (if I only add a Vector3 position, the rotation will be the same).
I am guessing you mean add a Transform, with position & rotation, and do what you say: (do transition from A to  X, then from X to B (X being the new rotation)

Comment: Add a new transform, you need to change position and rotation.

Comment: I'd approach it differently - create a gameobject which contains your camera, then parent that gameobject to the car. Rotating the gameobject will make the camera orbit the car, and have it always at a specific location (depending on your camera's local transform).

Answer (score 1):

I would 'move' the camera as you are doing now, but just use LookAt, or LookRotation, to point at the target. Lerping the transform.position should give you a smooth transition to the camera's rotation anyway, without the need to Slerp, but you could add some damping once you've got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public Transform target;

transform.LookAt(target);
```

attach this to camera

Comment: You'll need a bit more code there for this to be a valid script. You probably want the `transform.LookAt` to be inside an `Update` or `LateUpdate` method.